# Getting More than 1ip while using $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']

Tags: php

I am trying to make ip tracking system for my web and then inserting it into the sql.

But my problem is that on a single click i am getting 2-4ip in my sql.

Coding am using this currently.

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$referer=$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO `track`(`date`, `time`, `ip`, `referer`)       
VALUES ( CURDATE(), NOW(),'".$ip."', '".$referer."')");
echo"<script type='text/javascript'>
 window.location.href='http://example.com';
 </script>";
?>
```

When anyone click on this it is saving around 4ips that too different and even sometimes of different countries.

Why this problem is arising in my tracking system.

Comment: If you knew what this code was doing, you'd know that it wasn't possible for this to insert multiple values in one execution.

Comment: I know that its not possible  to insert multiple values in one execution but its happening but i am unable to get reason behind it @Devon

Comment: Clearly, it's being executed by 4 different systems, not saving 4 ips from one execution.  Compare with the server access log..

Comment: I Tried It. 10days

Comment: I tried just myself also when i click it save 2-4ips @Devon

Answer (score -1):

```
function getRealIpAddr()  
{  
    if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP']))  
    {  
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_CLIENT_IP'];  
    }  
    elseif (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR']))  
    //to check ip is pass from proxy  
    {  
        $ip=$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR'];  
    }  
    else 
    {  
        $ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];  
    }  
    return $ip;  
}
```